# CommandTimeout not working

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am trying to change the timeout for a SqlCommand query, in a method that tests my connection for a given connection string. The code is similar to this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...", connection);
      cmd.CommandTimeout = 10;
      connection.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      ...
      connection.Close();
    }
```

I would like to have a short timeout here, since I just want to test if this connection string is okay.
But, no matter what number I set on CommandTimeout (I tried 0, 1, 2, 4, 10, 30, 60, 120), my real time obtained for a dummy connection string is always about the same (total running time of about 15 seconds).

So, seems to me that the value I set on CommandTimeout is being ignored for some reason.

Any ideas why?

Comment: No idea, but the MSDN doco at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx states a couple of reasons it might be ignored. One is async use and using BeginExecuteReader which isn't your issue. However the other refers to timeout "..no effect when the command is executed against a context connection (a SqlConnection opened with "context connection=true" in the connection string)." Maybe check your connection string to see if this is the cause.

Comment: Yes, I checked the documentation a couple times to be sure I was not missing something there. Anyway, is not an async reader neither has the connection string any context.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but since you are utilizing a "using" block, you don't need to do connection.Close() as the end of scope on the using block would automatically close and dispose your connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>I think you're confusing what exactly `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` is for.  As per [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx):</s>

> Gets or sets the wait time before terminating **the attempt to execute a command** and generating an error.

In your case, you are executing a DataReader and stepping through your query (whatever it may be).  It is taking minimal time for each `Read()` which is why you wouldn't be hitting your timeout.

**Edit**:

If you are using a wrong connection string, your `Timeout` will not be the Command timeout, but it'll be the Connection time.  This defaults to 15 seconds.  That is the timeout that is effective in your situation.

You're going to timeout on the method call `SqlConnection.Open()`, not `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.  Therefore the `ConnectionTimeout` property is going to be the effective timeout value.

[SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout Property MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)

Comment: The point is, as I said on the question, I'm testing this with a wrong connection string, so I cannot actually Read anything. Because of that, I expected my executing time to be only about the timeout time.

Comment: @FlávioIvan Ah, ok.  I see.  Please see my edit.  Your `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` isn't what is going to be used for timeout in a bad connection.  That'll be the `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` property.

Comment: Thanks, Shark! I just tested it and now I see the execution time changing. It is still taking more to run than the timeout time I set, but now I can play with it. :)

Comment: "If you are using a wrong connection string" ---> And what is the fix for this? My connection string also has the "ConnectionTimeout" attribute. Is my connection string a "wrong connection string"?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to check the connection timeout which has a default of 15 seconds.

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx - if your connection string has context then CommandTimeout is ignored

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that on the question, but I don't have context on my connection string.

Comment: "You also need to check the connection timeout which has a default of 15 seconds." +1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your [SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify this in your connection string in your config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="*con_name*" connectionString="data source=*dsource*;initial catalog=*catalog*;integrated security=True;Connect Timeout=300;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```