# Connection Timeout argument passed doesn't work for a SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following connection string:

```
<add name="DatabaseServerInstance"
     providerName="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Server=xx.xx.x.xx; Database=db; User Id=user; Password=pass; TrustServerCertificate=true; Connection Timeout=2;" />
```

I have a WPF with a control calling a `MessageBox` to show whether the connection to the database is established or not and I want `Connection.Open()` to terminate early instead of the user having to wait 15 seconds for the failed connection message to be displayed, but `Connection Timeout=2` seems to do nothing.

An open connection gives an instantaneous response, while the failed connection despite the argument, loads with the average time no matter what the timeout is set to.

EDIT: This is the code for the sqlconnection call:

```
public class SqlPusher
{
    private static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseServerInstance"].ConnectionString;

    public Boolean TestConnection()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Debugger:
[image: Debugger]

Comment: Show us your code where you instantiate and open the SqlConnection. Also, is there a reason you're not using the async API?

Comment: Also, exactly which ADO.NET provider are you using? There's the in-box `System.Data.SqlClient` (for .NET Framework 4.x, which I think you're using? But you could also be using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` - or the (subtly different) post-.NET Core version of `System.Data.SqlClient` too.

Comment: @Dai Sorry, I am still new and haven't gotten around using async yet.  The NuGet packagse used are `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Configuration.Configurationmanager`

Comment: `private static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();` <-- You shouldn't keep a `SqlCommand` around in a static field like this - SqlCommand objects should be short-lived.

Comment: @Dai I removed the static keyword (the class isn't even static - I used some of my other code I am working on improving, where I was having a static class). It does nothing in the given context, though, as the WPF still takes ages (or rather 15 seconds) to display the timeout message

Comment: Use your debugger to set a breakpoint on the `new SqlConnection` line - does the debugger show that the actual runtime `connectionString` value still contains the `Connection Timeout=2` parameter? (It's possible that your runtime appSettings/`App.config` is different to your project's `app.config` file - do you have "Copy if newer" enabled in File Properties?)

Comment: @Dai Tried updating the property to `Copy if newer` - tried debugging and I can see the runtime value used is the one with the ``Connection Timeout=2` argument (added a photo to the post). Tried deleting `obj` and `bin` folders and rebuilding the solution and it still doesn't work

Comment: This looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085018/sqlconnection-doesnt-honor-timeout-for-ip-address-data-sources-net-core-2-2 - (I don't know for certain) but it's possible that the `Connection Timeout=` parameter only applies _after_ the `Data Source=` (i.e. server or instance name) is resolved - so if your DNS is down or your LAN is broken then that might be it. Is the SQL Server instance running locally? If so, what happens if you use the Shared Memory transport instead of TCP?

Comment: I think the only way to be sure is to use VS's ability to let you step-in-to .NET framework source-code to find out where and why the parameter isn't being honoured - or if it's getting blocked somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think either DNS lookups or SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol, or instance name lookups by way of SQL Browser service) are included in the Connection Timeout, so to remove those as a possibility connect directly to an instance's IP address and port when testing (don't use a host name and instance name).

Comment: Please check correct usage of SqlConnection class: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: @Aleksandar I'm voting to close as a typo because you used an impossible timeout. `20` may make sense but `2` isn't enough to complete DNS resolution, much less establish a connection. That's a "fail always" setting

Comment: Why are you using such a short timeout? This isn't even testing whether the server is up or not. It won't have enough time to detect if the client machine is connected or not. If you want to test the connection without blocking the application use `await conn.OpenAsync()`. WPF works perfectly fine with async/await, in fact the default `await` behavior was built for desktop applications. Data binding means you can easily update eg a status panel display with the connectivity status stored in a ViewModel.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But it should be doable without using async, shouldn't it?

Comment: Only if you want to block the UI thread. You didn't mention you're connecting over a VPN either. That's vital information. You also didn't explain what `while the failed connection despite the argument, loads with the average time` means. With a VPN, the *OS itself* doesn't know the network connection failed until it times out. There's no physical cable to check for signal.

Comment: Try `Connect Timeout` instead of `Connection Timeout`

Comment: from what i saw in the ms code, the setting isn't really honored anywhere, so you need to use some other means to handle it, for example by wrapping your code in a thread and timing yourself (and therefor ignoring results of connection.Open). Anyways, it's bad to use blocking methods like this inside GUI code. See also https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10991

Comment: you dont seem to have the providerName part of your connection string:   "....Connection Timeout=2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: @smoore4 It is included - I don't know how it didn't get into the pasted result.

Comment: The `TestConnection` code in the link provided by @siggemannen should fix this for you.  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10991#issuecomment-366328847

Comment: @BateTech Yeah, I read the thread and also think it will work - I will test it out later and report back. But seemingly, this also demonstrates the actual parameter is basically useless. Isn't this a quite clear functional flaw, which should be reported to Microsoft?

Comment: @siggemannen Your answer has been the only one working for me - cheers. Feel to comment it as an individual answer and I will award you the bounty.

Comment: @Aleksandar I don't think there is any way Microsoft would change this at this point, because it could be a breaking change for customers.  It would definitely be nice to have the docs updated to be more clear about this.  I did some testing also and for a server that isn't available the timeout was 30 secs, and for a server that was available but with a SQL logon trigger that waits for 1 min with a conn timeout of 2 and it waited 60 seconds before timing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i saw in the ms code, the setting isn't really honored anywhere, so you need to use some other means to handle it, for example by wrapping your code in a thread and timing yourself (and therefor ignoring results of Connection.Open). Anyways, it's bad to use blocking methods like this inside GUI code.

See also https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10991 for discussion and workarounds to handle connection timeouts

Comment: This is the only answer, which fully covered the topic and came up with a workable solution. I ended up altering the code from the page a bit from the thread (with the exact code segment being pointed out by @BateTech previously in the question comments from 'ralmsdeveloper' on GitHub):
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10991#issuecomment-366328847

Answer (score 1):

You could see what `ConnectionTimeout` means here: [What is "Connect Timeout" in sql server connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142746/what-is-connect-timeout-in-sql-server-connection-string)

To achieve desired behaviour you have to send Timeout in SqlCommand (BUT it requires to use proper ConnectionString otherwise it won't work, see - [CommandTimeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432409/commandtimeout-not-working)) , ***so anyway you must provide ConnectionTime property*** in you conn str, **or set it to 0 for indefinite wait** and exit by exception:

```cs
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
   cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;
```

After that you should execute you query i.e. insert/update/delete via `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, it internally uses timeout:

```cs
// inside ExecuteNonQuery method
this.InternalExecuteNonQuery((TaskCompletionSource<object>) null, nameof (ExecuteNonQuery), false, this.CommandTimeout, out bool _);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is several reason i think

first of all according to [this](https://groups.google.com/g/shinyapps-users/c/E1HqSxkm8es#:%7E:text=The%20connection%20timeout%20looks%20at,are%20on%20an%20appropriate%20plan.) use ConnectTimeout instead of Connection Timeout in the connection string.

second u can set the SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout  before opening the connection:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
  connection.ConnectionTimeout = 2;
  
}
```

the last one u can call SqlConnection.OpenAsync() instead of Open()  and pass a CancellationToken with a timeout this  will abort the async open after 2 seconds :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

  CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
  source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

  try 
  {
    await connection.OpenAsync(source.Token);
  
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // Handle timeout
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.1) class instead of a single string.

Comment: I tried this - it still defaults at the 30 seconds timeout.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can introduce your own timeout:

```
int timeout = 1000;
var task = connection.OpenAsync();
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
    // task completed within timeout
} else { 
    // timeout logic
}
```

See this SO question for more details:
[Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

Comment: I am not able to use asynch - it's really frustrating cauase the command seems simple, appears in the debugger and yet it still passes with the default time

Comment: @Aleksandar you're perfectly able to use async in WPF. You don't need your own timeout either. The entire question is based on incorrect assumptions, including how long a connection is supposed to take. Or how many steps it involves.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The connection timeout is an arbitrary value set to demonstrate not being able to connect as in needing to prompt a response after 2 seconds - it could just aswell be 5 seconds or 10 seconds. The WPF is for an assignment needing to be connected to VPN so I can in theory control myself whether I can connect or not as the response is instantenous when I am connected to the VPN, but defaults to the 30 seconds when not connected. Why can't I use my own timeout? It is a parameter after all fo the SqlConenctionStringBuilder

Comment: I meant `Task.Delay()`. Connecting over VPN means you have even *more* delays as the OS routes packets to the remote network and establishes a TCP connection. You should increase timeouts, not reduce them. Once that connection is established though, connection pooling means it will be reused automatically (assuming it was released with Dispose) without incurring the same connection cost

Answer (score 0):

I would do a fail fast approach using `TcpClient`, and then perform the actual `SqlConnection` for authentication

Here's my code:

```
public class SqlPusher
{
    private static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseServerInstance"].ConnectionString;

    public Boolean TestConnection()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

        #region quick-fail-test-using-tcp/sockets

        var server = builder.DataSource;
        var port = 1433; //default for sql server
        int TimeoutInMilliSeconds = 2000; //2 seconds

        if (server.Contains(',')) //parse "localhost,1433" into server & port
        { 
            var commaIndex = server.IndexOf(',');
            int.TryParse(server.Substring(commaIndex + 1), out port);
            server = server.Substring(0, commaIndex);
        }

        var tcpCheckPassed = false;
        try
        {
            using (var tcp = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
            {
                IAsyncResult result = tcp.BeginConnect(server, port, null, null);
                var connectResult = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeoutInMilliSeconds, true);
                if (connectResult && tcp.Connected)
                {
                    tcpCheckPassed = true;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            tcpCheckPassed = false;
        }

        if (!tcpCheckPassed)
            return false;  //tcp failed - no point continuing further.

        #endregion


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have always used 30 as the default connection timeout in our apps in the connection string.
13 years ago someone asked the same question on Stack overflow as you have.

[connection timeout property in connection string ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265733/connection-timeout-property-in-connection-string-ignored)

Seems 15 is the minimum and you are trying to set the value lower than 15 which won't work. One of the suggestions on above link is to try [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Since you have already tried it as suggested above by Signalist. May be try how it was suggested by Oppositional on the link I pasted here. They seemed to make it work.

Comment: The documentation page doesn't seem to have any remakrs regarding a minimal value:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

I have tried running it at both 15 and 30 resulting in the same exception being thrown, as desired, but after 47 seconds. Assuming the extra time in both cases is an artefact caused by the time taken to estalbish the connection the one should still be faster than the other. It can't really wrap my head around what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

change "connection timeout = 2" for "connect timeout = 2".
That worked for me.

```
<add name="DatabaseServerInstance" 
     connectionString="Server=xx.xx.x.xx; Database=db; User Id=user; Password=pass; TrustServerCertificate=true; Connect Timeout=2;" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - tried it, but sadly it didnt change nothing

Answer (score 0):

Verify timeout expired errors
When you encounter "timeout expired" issues, you receive one or more of the following error messages:

Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgment. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was [Pre-Login] initialization=23; handshake=14979;
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out.

Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgment. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.
The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was [Pre-Login] initialization=21036; handshake=0; (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2).

System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.