# Problem with connection timeout SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout, sqlconnection

I'm developing a Windows service in C# that collects data from SQL Server in another machine on the local network.

However, it is necessary to deal with if this other machine is not available, and as it is a local network, the timeout for opening the connection can be very small (10 seconds).

I defined connection timeout in the connection string, but it is not working. I try the "Connect Timeout" property too.

When the code executes `sqlconn.Open` without the other machine in the network being active, it's taking almost two minutes to return the timeout, and I set it to 10 seconds.

I read some cases on the site that encourage creating your own timeout mechanism using async/await, but I don't think I can use that in my code, any ideas what I can do?

Here's my code:

```
        public struct E3Data
        {
            public DateTime dt;
            public float value;
        }
        
        public E3Data GetSQLData()
        {
            E3Data e3 = new E3Data()
            string queryString = "SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(HOUR,DATEDIFF(HOUR,CAST(E3TimeStamp AS DATE),E3TimeStamp),CAST(CAST(E3TimeStamp AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) As DateFormatted, [Nível Montante TDA (m)] AS Nivel FROM " + strtable+"_SASE ORDER BY E3TimeStamp DESC";
            string connectionString = "Server=192.168.80.4;Database=COR;User Id=user;Password=pass;Connect Timeout=5";
            
            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, sqlconn);
                
                try
                {
                    sqlconn.Open(); //here's the problem. In case other machine not available, the timeout must act within 5 seconds
                    SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.read();
                    e3.Value = reader["Level"]
                    e3.dt = reader["dateF"]
                    
                    reader.Close()
                }
                catch
                {
                    log("DB Open error");
                }
                return e3;
            }
```

Comment: There is a timeout for it, you just need to find it. Showing your relevant code would also be useful.

Comment: i eddited the post with code

Comment: Try "Connection Timeout" instead of "Connect Timeout". May (be) help.(?)

Comment: I tried both options. None worked

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319434/connection-timeout-argument-passed-doesnt-work-for-a-sqlconnection

Comment: Why exactly can't you use async+await with SqlConnection.OpenAsync and a CancellationTokenSource? Have you tried?

Comment: You could try to set the connection timeout on your SqlCommand. `sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 5;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection Timeout argument passed doesn't work for a SqlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319434/connection-timeout-argument-passed-doesnt-work-for-a-sqlconnection)

Comment: I had already read the solutions in the previous links. It seems like the solution is to actually insert code for us to handle the timeout. What I'm going to do is increase the interval of my periodic executions in such a way that the timeout being applied does not interfere with the code. Thanks a lot for the help.